# Separate virtualenv for vim plugins and application code

Tags: python, plugin

I have multiple vim plugins (ropevim, taskwarrior etc.) which depend on python libraries. These libraries are installed in system python3

When I am working on a python project, the virtual environment for that project does not have these libraries. Resulting in these plugins not working and dumping a ton of error messages on the console.

Is it possible to ensure that vim always uses the same virtual environment (or system python env) for its plugins irrespective of what the shell virtualenv is?

**Note** I had asked this Q. on stackoverflow. someone recommended asking in this sub group. I will close the Q. there

Comment: I think virtualenv is based on a bunch of environment variables? You can set those in Vim with `let $VARNAME = 'value'`. I'm not really familiar with virtualenv, but you can probably do a bit of muckery with that to ensure it's set up correctly, for example by prefixing `$PATH` with the desired virtualenv (and maybe also some others, like some `$PYTHON*` ones). Check `env | grep -i python` to see what it sets.

Comment: You are correct. The `activate` script backs-up the system PATH and PYTHON_HOME to _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH and _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME. So checking for and restoring them before the call to `vundle#begin()` should do the trick.

Comment: Hmm... I spoke too soon, these variables are not exported hence are not visible in vimscript... 
VIRTUAL_ENV is exported, I will have to check for that and use regex to clean up the path.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following snippet at the start of `.vimrc` restores the default python environment.

```
if has_key(environ(),"VIRTUAL_ENV")
        let $PATH=substitute($PATH,join([$VIRTUAL_ENV,"bin:"],"/"),"","g")
endif
```

Comment: A slightly nicer way to write that might be something like `let $PATH = $PATH->split(':')->filter({_, v -> v !~ '^' .. $VIRTUAL_ENV})->join(':')`; this splits `$PATH` to a list, and it will still work if `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin` happens to be the last entry in `$PATH`.